# This jQuery each() loop keeps returning the last color only (Color Thief)

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, color-thief

Using the [Color Thief](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/) javascript effect, I have written some code that grabs an images dominant color and adjusts the entire theme's color scheme based on the image.

This all works well on a single product page, where only **one** image is being used. On my catalog page, there are multiple images that I need to grab the dominant color from. One image for each product. I need to display each separate color along with the product.

---

You can see the colored `border` in each product's panel (it's a brown/orange color).

[image]

---

My very slimmed-down code I'm using is below:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    var image = new Image;
    var bg;
    $('.post-image-hidden-container').each(function() {
        bg = $(this).text();

        image.onload = function() {
            var colorThief = new ColorThief();
            var dominantColor = colorThief.getColor(image);
            var colorPalette = colorThief.getPalette(image, 7);
            var backgroundColor = 'rgb('+ dominantColor +')';

            /* Calculate the Lightest Color in the Palette */
            var lightestColor = colorPalette.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
                var currLightNess = (0.2126*currentValue[0] + 0.7152*currentValue[1] + 0.0722*currentValue[2]);
                var prevLightNess = (0.2126*previousValue[0] + 0.7152*previousValue[1] + 0.0722*previousValue[2]);
                return (prevLightNess < currLightNess) ? currentValue : previousValue;
            });

            /* Calculate the Darkest Color in the Palette */
            var darkestColor = colorPalette.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
                var currLightNess = (0.2126*currentValue[0] + 0.7152*currentValue[1] + 0.0722*currentValue[2]);
                var prevLightNess = (0.2126*previousValue[0] + 0.7152*previousValue[1] + 0.0722*previousValue[2]);
                return (prevLightNess > currLightNess) ? currentValue : previousValue;
            });

            /* Create Shades and Tints of Lightest Color */
            ...

            /* Shades (darker) */
            ...

            /* Tints (lighter) */
            ...

            /* Handle all CSS based on returned colors */
            $('.product-bottom-info-container').each(function() {
                $(this).css({
                    borderTop: '3px solid rgb('+ lightestColor +')'
                });
            });
        }
        image.src = bg;
    });
});
```

Right after declaring the variable `bg` I wrapped the entire thing in an `each()` loop. Down towards the bottom, `.product-bottom-info-container` is the element where the colored border appears. I cannot seem to get each product's border to be it's own color. It keeps giving every border the LAST color in the loop.

**Some notes:**

- `.post-image-hidden-container` is a hidden div above each product that contains the product's image url.
- `.product-bottom-info-container` is the container at the bottom of each product with the product title and the colored border.

Am I using the `each()` function properly? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**
I was able to grab all of the RGB values for each image and put them into an array:

```
var thisColor;
var theseColors = [];

$('.shop-page-item-thumb').each(function() {
    $(this).find('img').each(function() {
        thisColor = colorThief.getColor(this);
        theseColors.push(thisColor);
    });
});
```

Now that I have all RGB's available, is there a way to simply loop through this array and assign each value to its respective .product-bottom-info-container element?

`theseColors[0]` is the first RGB, `theseColors[1]` is the second, etc. all the way up to `theseColors[11]`.

If I run `console.log(thisColor)` inside of the loop, I get these results:

```
[29, 28, 22]
[217, 195, 189]
[14, 14, 8]
[233, 232, 206]
[31, 31, 31]
[82, 97, 111]
[60, 68, 84]
[34, 29, 30]
[17, 30, 37]
[12, 11, 12]
[56, 43, 26]
[209, 150, 108]
```

The 12 RGB values that I need. So we're headed in the right direction.

---

**UPDATE for Mottie**
Here is the HTML structure for one of the products. `.shop-page-item-thumb` is the container that holds the thumbnail, but `.shop-page-item-article` is the parent (besides the actual `li` list item).

[image]

---

**FINAL UPDATE (Thanks Mottie!)**
This is the piece of code that finally worked:

```
$('.shop-page-item-thumb').each(function() {
    var thumb = $(this);
    thumb.find('img').each(function() {
        thisColor = colorThief.getColor(this);
        thumb.parent().find('.product-bottom-info-container').css({
            borderTop: '3px solid rgb('+ thisColor +')'
        })
    });
});
```

Much love, **Stack Overflow**! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this code is looping through each container after each image load...

```
/* Handle all CSS based on returned colors */
$('.product-bottom-info-container').each(function() {
  $(this).css({
    borderTop: '3px solid rgb('+ lightestColor +')'
  });
});
```

try this instead:

```
$(this).closest('.product-bottom-info-container').css({
  borderTop: '3px solid rgb('+ lightestColor +')'
});
```

---

Update: Oh sorry, I didn't look at the code that closely... another problem is the `image` definition. There is only one, not one for each container... Instead of defining it outside the loop, find it inside of the `.each` loop and then attach an onload...

```
$(this).find('img')[0].onload = function() {
```

It shouldn't change the above code that adds the border color since `this` would refer to the image inside of the `onload` function.

It would have been easier to troubleshoot the problem if you would have provided a ready-made demo to use.

---

Update2: Instead of pushing the colors to an array, apply them directly to the border; I have no idea about the thumb images in relation to the containers, so we're just going to assume that the thumbs are in the same order as the containers. <del>Some HTML would have helped</del>. Updated for the given HTML...

```
$('.shop-page-item-thumb').each(function() {
    var thumb = $(this);
    thumb.find('img').each(function() {
        thisColor = colorThief.getColor(this);
        // prev() targets the previous element (it should be
        // the 'product-bottom-info-container'; or use
        // thumb.parent().find('.product-bottom-info-container')
        thumb.prev().css({
            borderTop: '3px solid rgb('+ thisColor +')'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Mottie, thanks for the reply. Still not working unfortunately. Not getting any errors, just no color at all now. I'm going to play with this some more. :)

Comment: Mottie, before your update I was headed in the right direction. Question - I was able to get all of the RGB values into an array. Would I then be able to simply use each array value for each .product-bottom-info-container border color? I'll update my question with my updated code. I'll also try to implement your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: I'd make a demo for you, but Color Thief is funky and doesn't allow using remote images with the script. Only local images.

Comment: Mottie, I can't get it working. I've played around with your suggestion, and I can't even get anything in the console this way. Color Thief is a beast, and the documentation is very limited. But we'll figure it out eventually! Thanks

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Is `shop-page-item-thumb` a wrapper for all the containers?

Comment: Added a screenshot of the html structure for a product. Thanks

Comment: Is there more than one image inside of the "thumb" div?... did you try the code from my last update?

Comment: I've modified the last update... I hope you figure it out, I'm signing out for tonight.